# why some images do not show up inside PDF when viewed inside some browsers?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I do not know if this is a `Latex` issue or browser issue. That is why I am asking here first.

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

This is my image

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}
\end{document}
```

The `image.pdf` file is in same folder. When compiled using `lualatex foo.tex` and viewing the foo.pdf inside some browsers, the image do not appear on screen.

```
lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.146 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(./foo.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}<./imag
e.pdf>] (./foo.aux))
 377 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 44 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:27,3:6,4:1,5:23,6:2,7:35,9:16,11:1
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman12-regular.
otf>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 78909 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

Looking at the pdf generated in local adobe PDF reader, the image shows up OK.

But when I open the same PDF inside Chrome or Brave browsers, the image do not show up. The image shows up when viewed inside Edge or Firefox browsers.

This only affects some images and not all.

I do not know if it has something to do with how the pdf is generated by `lulatex`. I also tried `pdflatex`, no difference.

My question is: Is this in any way related to How Latex generated the pdf file, or is this a bug in these browsers PDF readers? I have no idea why only some images have this problem and not others.

I put on my site on this folder [here](https://www.12000.org/tmp/10302019/) the image.pdf and generated foo.pdf and also foo.tex

The image.pdf was generated from IPE program. I never had problem with its pdf files. So I do not know why this one do not show up in some browsers.

Comment: I can confirm that the image does not show up when viewing your `foo.pdf` in Chrome browser, though it shows up in most other PDF viewers. Interesting.

Comment: your `image.pdf` shows the lines but no text in chrome, but works in firefox, edge, acrobat and xpdf. It is probably worth submitting that as a chrome bug report, see what they say. If the browser can not display the original  image it is not likely to display it included in a document.

Comment: My (blind) guess is that Chrome PDF viewer has some max depth it will follow PDF object resources to (like a depth of 50 or 64 or something), and as you nest things more and more deeply, things fall off that limit and don't get rendered.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR So why does it not display correctly when viewed on its own? (See David's comment.)

Comment: I've had problems with Metapost images not displaying or displaying incorrectly in `chromium`. I don't know how IPE does things, so no idea if that might be related. (The images are converted to PDF on-the-fly in my case, using the usual `graphicx` configuration.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, David's comment was the reason for mine – my guess (almost entirely unsubstantiated, but made after a cursory look at the PDF file structure) is that the text (or the font object) in `image.pdf` is “too deep” for Chrome/Chromium, and when `image.pdf` is itself included in `foo.pdf`, most of it becomes too deep.

Comment: If pdfcrop has caused the problem it would be good to add it to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Your PDF has objects too deeply nested, and different viewers have different limits for nesting depth.

---

- To confirm/illustrate the problem: your `foo.pdf` does not show the included `image.pdf` in the Chrome PDF viewer:

  [image: in chrome]
- while it works fine in other viewers:

  [image: in Preview]
- As David pointed out, the problem already exists with `image.pdf`, where Chrome does not show the text:

  [image: image.pdf in Chrome]
- while other viewers do:

  [image: image.pdf in Preview]
- The problem probably has to do with the structure of the PDF, and opening up your `image.pdf` (or `foo.pdf` for that matter) with qpdf or [iText RUPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869377/4958) shows that the PDF is deeply nested:

  [image: viewed in RUPS]

  Some of the text / fonts seem to be at the deepest layer, and these are what do not show up in Chrome.

  You can also just search for something like `CreationDate` in the file, to see that it contains many PDFs:

  ```
  /CreationDate (D:20191029080119-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029074018-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029073712-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029065739-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029065707-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029065458-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029065024-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029032054-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029031857-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029021955-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029021626-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029021103-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191029020932-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20191027235854-05'00')
  /CreationDate (D:20190513215137)
  /CreationDate (D:20191029123721-05'00')
  ```
- This suggests that Chrome has a lower max depth it's willing to render. We can experiment!

---

Create a `simple.pdf` out of the following `simple.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

And we can try to include this PDF recursively and see how far we can go. Long story short, in your shell you can write the following loop to create 100 PDFs:

```
cp simple.pdf test-0.pdf
for n in {1..100}; do m=$(($n - 1)); echo $m $n; echo -E "\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} $n [\includegraphics{test-$m}] $n \end{document}" > test-$n.tex; pdflatex test-$n.tex; done
```

This results in 100 PDFs named `test-1.pdf` to `test-100.pdf`. For example this is `test-5.pdf` which is rendered successfully in all viewers:

[image: test-5, Chrome]

This is Chrome successfully displaying `test-30.pdf`:

[image]

while at `test-31.pdf` it drops the innermost “hello”:

[image: test-31, Chrome]

and at `test-32.pdf` it drops two of the innermost ones, i.e. it only renders up to a depth of ~30 (off by 1 or 2 depending on how you count):

[image: test-32, Chrome]

Meanwhile, Preview is fine until `test-49.pdf` (although if you look closely, part of the "Hello" is cut off at the bottom — but that may be a separate rounding issue):

[image: test-49, Preview]

and it starts dropping at `test-50.pdf`:

[image: test-50, Preview]

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC does a tiny bit better, as it starts dropping at `test-53.pdf`:

[image: test-53, Acrobat Reader]

It also says there's an error:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.

If you open `test-100.pdf`, in Chrome you can see numbers starting at 70, in Preview starting at 51, and in Acrobat Reader starting at 48.

---

If you look up the [PDF reference version 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html), there's an Appendix C: Implementation Limits ([page 991](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf#page=991)), which says:

> In general, PDF does not restrict the size or quantity of things described in the file format, such as numbers, arrays, images, and so on. However, a PDF consumer application running on a particular processor and in a particular operating environment does have such limits.

and has a table C.1 about which it says “applications producing PDF files are strongly advised to remain within them”. One of the limits is on q/Q nesting depth:

[image: q/Q limit]

This seems to be exactly the limit you're hitting, though all viewers seem to be slightly more generous (some more than others) than that.

Comment: Does this imply a bug in the tool that created image.pdf? I believe pdfcrop may be the culprit.

Comment: @Anush I'm not sure how `image.pdf` got so nested. I can imagine pdfcrop adding one level of nesting, but not so many.